# Add comment with Inline Entity Form while adding content

Tags: 7, entities

I'm creating a content type. and want to add comment for the same content on same form of add content.

I've installed [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), and selected *Entity reference* as **Field type** & selected *Inline entity form - multiple values* as the widget. I've chosen **Selected Target** type *Comment* under **FIELD SETTINGS** and I'm still not getting the comment section on content addition form.

Why is it not showing? Is there another way to show comment on content addition form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline Entity Form doesn't support Comment forms out of the box.

Part of the process of building the IEF widget is a call to [`inline_entity_form_get_controller()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/inline_entity_form/tree/inline_entity_form.module?h=7.x-1.8#n94) which will retrieve a controller class from the entity metadata. As you can see in IEF's [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/inline_entity_form/tree/inline_entity_form.module?h=7.x-1.8#n110) invocation, it only adds this controller metadata for node, taxonomy, commerce product, & commerce line item entities.

Theoretically, you could build your own custom module that could:

1. Invoke `hook_entity_info_alter()` to add support for comment entities.
2. Build your own custom class that extends `EntityInlineEntityFormController`(e.g. `CommentInlineEntityFormController`) to be evoked for form processing.

Keep in mind this is an unusual use case, a comment entity is predicated on a *its parent entity pre-existing before it's created*; you're likely to run against logic that might prevent this (e.g. database integrity checks) .

It might be easier just to create your own custom node type entity that's configured just to appear like comments on your nodes.

Comment: "It might be easier just to create your own custom node type entity that's configured just to appear like comments on your nodes." - this is what I would suggest. The D7 comment entity was not built very well, it was only designed to work with Nodes, and no other entity types, and it comes with all sorts of other issues. Creating new node types or entity types for comments makes them a lot easier to work with.